# Problem in connecting WiFi on A Dell Inspiron 1420

Tags: wireless, networking, dell, inspiron

my Dell Inspiron running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, cant detect WiFi Signals and even not showing wifi icon also. I have tried several methods after reading around 20-25 Forums and blogs, but still their is no solution :( How should i go about fixing it... Its my First Installtion/Interaction with Linux !! Please suggest me what to do...Thanks a lot for all your help guys...

Comment: did u try system settings->network->wireless->on? if so paste this on terminal sudo iwconfig and if u can please upload a screenshot of it.

Answer (score -1):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```